# Elasticsearch template to support case insensitive searches

Tags: elasticsearch

I've setup a normalizer on an index field to support case insensitive searches, cant seem to get it to work.

```
GET users/
```

Returns the following mapping:

```
{
  "users": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "normalize": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "search_normalizer"
              }
            }
          },
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "users",
        "creation_date": "1567936315432",
        "analysis": {
          "normalizer": {
            "search_normalizer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type": "custom"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "5SknFdwJTpmF",
        "version": {
          "created": "6040299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although `first_name` is normalized to lowercase, queries on the `first_name` field are case sensitive.

Using the following query for a user with first name `Dave`

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "first_name": {
              "value": ".*dave.*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET users/_analyze
{
    "analyzer" : "standard",
    "text": "Dave"
}
```

returns

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "dave",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Although "Dave" is tokenized to "dave" the following query

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "first_name": "dave"
    }
  }
}
```

Returns no hits.

Is there an issue with my current mapping? or the query?

Comment: please share _analyze API result against "users" indices for "Dave" word.

Comment: Also, I don't know why you are using regex query when you can analyze and index the data. and what is the purpose of dots in regex query?

Comment: @hamidbayat added the analyzer query, the dot asterix in the regex im looking for any name with the substring 'dave' in it, dot asterix means zero or more chars of any type prior to the 'dave' substring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed **first_name.normalize** in query

### Indexing Records

```
{"first_name": "Daveraj"}
{"index": {}}
{"first_name": "RajdaveN"}
{"index": {}}
{"first_name": "Dave"}
```

### Query

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "first_name.normalize": {
              "value": ".*dave.*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Result

````
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test3",
                "_type": "test3_type",
                "_id": "M8-lEG0BLCpzI1hbBWYC",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "first_name": "Dave"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test3",
                "_type": "test3_type",
                "_id": "Mc-lEG0BLCpzI1hbBWYC",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "first_name": "Daveraj"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test3",
                "_type": "test3_type",
                "_id": "Ms-lEG0BLCpzI1hbBWYC",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "first_name": "RajdaveN"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}```
````

Comment: Im pretty sure there's not need to explicitly specific first_name.normlize

Comment: If i don't give normalize then results are => {
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test3",
                "_type": "test3_type",
                "_id": "Ms-lEG0BLCpzI1hbBWYC",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "first_name": "RajdaveN"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have created a normalized multi-field: `first_name.normalize` , but you are searching on the original field `first_name` which doesn't have any analyzer specified (will default to index-default analyzer or `standard`).
The examples given here might help:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

You need to explicitly specify the `multi-field` you want to search on, note even though a `multi-field` cant have its own content, it indexes different terms as opposed to its parent (although not always) as a result of possibly being analyzed using diff analyzers/char/token filters.